Bending radius not satisfied in electric meters
In electric meters, bending radius can't be satisfied due to sharp turns at the connections. In the following is actual AWG 1 wire in the electric meter, what would happen here and how to satisfy the radius?



look for a meter base that has angled connections

what is the bend radius requirement you need to satisfy?

This is purely a mechanical concern, not electrical. I would either consult your cable or connector supplier on recommendations.

the red wire does not have to stay on the left side of the centerline ... likewise for the black

Jtl - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. For each image: If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page etc. More rules in [tour] & [help].

sorry.. the above edited is an actual AWG 1 inside an electric meter in our building.. how can you fit AWG 1 in such space and still satisfying the radius?

This looks like a U.S. service which needs to follow the National Electric Code, unless local rules dictate otherwise.
The type of wire you show looks like it falls under Type TC cable (common types are THHN, THWN-2, etc). In the NEC code (2017 & 2020), paragraph 336.24 it states that the minimum bend radius is 4 times the overall diameter for wire diameters under 1.0 inches and voltages under 1000 volts. #10 THHN wire has an overall diameter of 0.149 inches. This means the minimum radius is about 0.60 inches. That's not too hard to attain in that space as shown in the image below. The green circle represents the minimum bend radius for the conductors shown in your image.

Too sharp of a bend radius can stress the copper conductor and insulation. Very sharp bends can work harden the copper which increases the brittleness.

please see edit.. it is actual AWG 1 in the electric meter.. how can you satisfy the radius inside it?

Your original image, as shown as a crop in my answer, shows wire that was closer to #10. The green circle was scaled off of the diameter of the wire shown in the original image. I agree that in your new image, a proper bend radius could not be attained and shows damage to the insulation jacket from pliers and and a very tight bend radius. The job could have been done better within the limited space, but probably not to spec. One thing going for your installation is the wire is stranded which means the copper probably isn't stressed except for the application of pliers.

The load connected is 100 A. Will the bend heat up and break? What do you think?
